# how to take parent node attribute in xslt without using template

Tags: xslt

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<student_list>
<ID No="A-1">
<name>Jon</name>
<mark>80</mark>
</ID>
<ID No="A-2">
<name>Ray</name>
<mark>81</mark>
</ID>
</student_list>
```

my xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//ID">
     ID:string:"
<xsl:value-of select="@No"/>"
          </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
      name:string:"<xsl:apply-templates />"
     </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mark">
      mark:string:"<xsl:apply-templates />"
     </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output expected:
ID:string:"A-1"
name:string:"jon"
mark:string:"80"
ID:string:"A-2"
name:string:"Ray"
mark:string:"81"

some one plz help.

---

Thanks for response, really great i got the output by updating the above code, But how can i get line break for each and every line in "text output" mode.i tried using this code:

```
<xsl:template name="Newline"><xsl:text> 
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

line--1
 <xsl:call-template name="Newline" /> 
line--2
```

but this is not giving me line break. any information will be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks like you've added an answer as an update to your question... please add this as an edit to your question to make it easier for others to see and answer it. Edits move your question up in the queue, so it will get more traffic this way too!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the **name** and **mark** elements are children of the **ID** element, but in your template that matches the **ID** you do not have any code to continue to process the children, and so they are not matched.

Change your **ID** matching template to the following:

```
<xsl:template match="//ID"> 
   ID:string:"<xsl:value-of select="@No"/>" 
   <xsl:apply-templates /> 
</xsl:template>
```

If you are concerned about new line, it would probably be better to do something like this (Where  is a carriage return to get a new line)

```
<xsl:template match="//ID">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('ID:string:&quot;', @No, '&quot;&#13;')" />
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Or maybe this....

```
<xsl:template match="//ID">
   <xsl:text>ID:string:"</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="@No" />
   <xsl:text>"&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="//ID">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('ID:string:&quot;', @No, '&quot;&#13;')" />
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="name|mark">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name()), ':string:&quot;', ., '&quot;&#13;')" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should then give your expected results.

```
ID:string:"A-1"
name:string:"Jon"
mark:string:"80"
ID:string:"A-2"
name:string:"Ray"
mark:string:"81"
```

Note how I have combined the templates for **name** and **mark** to share code.

Comment: Thanks for response friend, really great i got the output by updating the above code, But how can i get line break for each and every line in text output.i tried using this code:
<xsl:template name="Newline"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:template>

line--1
<xsl:call-template name="Newline" />
line--2

but this is not giving me line break. any information will be helpful.

Thanks again.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to show how to cope with line-breaks, but you do really need to make this clear in your original question, rather than in comments. Thanks